# How to get SimplePie to fail gracefully on invalid feed?

Tags: simplepie

I'm trying to get SimplePie to fail gracefully if one of the feeds I hand it turns out to be unavailable or invalid (due to server issues on the feed provider's end)

The code I've got is this:

```
$this->feed= new SimplePie();
// Set which feed to process.
$this->feed->set_feed_url('http://my_feed_goes_here'); // Bogus
$this->feed->handle_content_type();

// Run SimplePie.
$this->feed->init();
```

The problem is, if the feed_url turns out to be invalid, I get the following error as soon as it hits `$this->feed->init();`

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::getLineNo()
```

I've looked through the documentation, and I can't see anything about validating.  I did see this page about error checking (http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/error) but that only really works if the URL is completely invalid and fails to load.  In a case where the URL comes back with a 404, or something else that is not a valid feed, $feed->error is blank.

Isn't there some mechanism built into SimplePie to allow me to see whether I got a valid feed back, so I can fail gracefully if I didn't?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of SimplePie?

Comment: Yes, I am on 1.3.1, which is the latest and greatest.

Answer (score 2):

In SimplePie 1.3.1, `->init()` will return false if it can't read or parse  the URL, so you might do this:

```
if (! $feed->init()) {
    // log your error, "return false" or handle the failure some other way
}
```

Based on my reading of  `simplepie\library\SimplePie.php`, it doesn't generate any exceptions and that's why Try/Catch won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be built into SimplePie, but in your calling PHP you could use a try/catch block:

```
try {
    $this->feed->init();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Although depending on the error, this might not work either.

Comment: hmm, I'll check into that and get back to you.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that didn't get it either.  Still getting the fatal error.

Comment: Hm, could be a bug in SimplePie. If you're brave you could try to trace where it's failing and fix the bug.

Comment: Looks like the same issue as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574433/simplepie-fails-to-import-a-feed-but-the-error-is-blank?rq=1